# Clarifications on google custom search API v1 parameters

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I am experimenting with the google custom search API (free version) for performing image search. I would like to commence with the paid version. However, I have some difficulties in understanding the pricing and some documented query parameters in the API calls at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest#api-specific_query_parameters

1) In the free version, we have 100 queries/day. If I understood well, 1 query means a single API call. This call can return a maximum of 10 (since the parameter 'num' takes a maximum value of 10) results only. Is this both for free and paid versions? Or is it possible to retrieve more results per API request in the paid version? Precisely, can 'num' take values greater than 10?

2) The parameter 'start' is documented as index of the first result to return. In the free version, I cannot get more than 100 results for a specific query (parameter 'q'). To summarize precisely, I can get 10 results/API call, each call with parameter 'start' taking the values 1, 11,... 91 and same value for 'q'. The API call returns an error for any value of 'start' greater than 91. Is n't the free version supposed to allow 100 API calls? Or perhaps, this restriction is placed to avoid being able to retrieve more than 100 results per search term 'q'?

3) In the paid version, are API calls which return non-200 responses billed for as well?

4) In the paid version, how many API calls can be made for a specific search term 'q'?

5) Do you think there are particular restrictions with respect to the number of results that apply specific to image search only?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The results are paginated. The search results show 10 per page. If you want more you need to set the start page to 11 & get 10 more. It is an exact imitation of what would happen in Google UI search. If you have trouble understanding goto Google search and observe the results. It should match almost. parameter n must be the number of results per page.

In the free version you have 100 free/day. Anything else will 0.5 cents per request. You cannot make more 10k calls per day. So free is not actually free.

In the "paid" version you can buy in bulk. AFAIK there is no daily limit. You can "buy" let us say 11000 requests for 55$ (11000*0.5) and use it all up in one day. But the paid version will be ended soon :( . Please check this blog for info https://customsearch.googleblog.com/